# Double quotes in user input in C++

Tags: c++

The user want to enter the input
`;. ,?!"=':`

```
int main()
{

string sep;
    cout << "Enter the separators: " << endl;
    cin >> sep;
}
```

I wrote the above program but when i print the sep variable it does not show the string after double quotes.
How can we read the double quotes enter by the user?

Comment: Formatted input `>>` stops when it hits whitespace. There's a space in your input. You should use `std::getline` instead.

Comment: The program above does not print chars before the double quotes as well. Because it prints nothing.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, your question should include both the expected and actual output of your program (which implies also changing your program so that it actually has output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it does not show anything after the space either. The input (`;. ,?!"=':`) you use has a space after the dot(.) and it does not print anything after that. it's because, as the @Retired Ninja mentioned in the comment,

> "Formatted input >> stops when it hits whitespace."

You can use `getline` if you want to take the entire line(with space) as an input. Please, check the example bellow

```
int main()
{
    string sep;
    cout << "Enter the separators: " << endl;
    getline(cin, sep);
    cout<<"Entered string is => "<<sep;
    return 0;
}
```